# How to add push notification service to your app?

Tags: service, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I want to add Apple push notification service to my app.The detail is:

my app will store some important personal data,so ,i want to sure that when someone lost s/he's iPhone,s/he can report to the server which provide service to my app.When the server receive the report,it'll send a notification to the APNS,then the APNS send a push notification to the iPhone and call that app to delete the relative data.
Here is my question:

1. How to begin all these? Should I apply any certification or ID?
2. Is it possible to call a app that might not be running at the time to delete some data?

Answer (score 0):

I'd head on over to Urban Airship and play around with their implementation of Apple Push Notifications. They have a sample application you can extend to fit your need and great step-by-step documentation on how to get your sample application up and running.

A number of "where is my iPhone" app's out there are already using the approach you are describing to geographically locate an iPhone.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

There are tons of information in Apple Developer:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html

The easyest way to do a quick test is look into [easyapns](http://www.easyapns.com/) documentation. When you create your AppID in the [iOS Provisioning Portal](https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action) you must configure it for Apple Push Notification service (read the "how to" tab).

There is no problem if your app is not running, when a Push is recieved, your app will be notifyed by the `UIApplicationDelegate` with this message:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

There is where you must place your deletion code.